# How to enable 'preserve logs' in chrome remote browser using selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, saucelabs

I have tried to enable 'preserve logs' of network console using robot class but it is not working for the remote browser(I am using sauce labs). Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of the HAR files and console logs from Sauce Labs when using Chrome or Firefox by turning on `extendedDebugging` in your capabilities. The files can be obtained by downloading them from the UI or accessing via API. Check out the Sauce Labs [Extended Debugging Documentation](https://docs.saucelabs.com/insights/debug/index.html).

Comment: This is the way to do it!  They'll all be available for your entire team to view (until the test assets expire, at least).